# Is there a way to make my code on making picture boxes transparent shorter? C# beginner

Tags: c#

I am trying to make 4 picture boxes transparent so that the background shows. This is what I have:

```
pbBordermain.Controls.Add(pb1);
pbBordermain.Controls.Add(pb2);
pbBordermain.Controls.Add(pb3);
pbBordermain.Controls.Add(pb4);
pb1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
pb2.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
pb3.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
pb4.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

- Is there a way I can make it shorter?
- I tried using commas to separate the picturboxes but came up error. Why is that?

Comment: Repeated actions are typically best handled by a loop. If you've got a lot of picture boxes, you can add them to a collection and loop through them, setting each to Color.Transparent

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the "comma separation?" It's not quite clear which part you separated and how

Comment: If this is actually about __four__ pbs then it is just fine.  If this is about a __dynamic__ number do put them in a `List<T>` and loop over it. Shorter is __not__ always better: The `List<PictureBox>` solution will be a little __longer__ but __better__.

Comment: i tried separating the picture boxes inside the () such as .Add(pb1, pb2,pb3,pb4); I am going to use these picture boxes through drag and drop. I was thinking about making a list?

Answer (score 2):

The important part of this question is: will you ever need to access the PictureBox on your code? If no, you can do something like this:

```
for (int=0;i<numberOfPictureBoxes;i++)
{
    pbBorderMain.Controls.Add(new PictureBox() {
        BackColor = Color.Transparent
    });
}
```

Accessing the components after constructing them this way it's possible, but would add unecessary complexity to your code. I would only recomend this if you have a dynamic number of elements. For a fixed number, your alternative may not look the best but is much easier to maintain in the future.

Comment: i need to use the picture boxes through drag and drop

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with the other answers that say your code is fine how it is.

What happens when you want to add or remove a picture box? What happens when you want to change the setup routine by changing size, or choosing a different background color, or doing *anything else* that works with these items as a group? You'd have to change your code all over the place and add and remove stuff a line at a time over and over.

No, instead you should start making some functions. What are you doing when you set these properties. Is this some kind of initial setup? Well, make a function that has the name `Setup` in it. Call it for each picture box.

```
// The setup routine that is the one place in your system that knows how to do this task
public void SetUpPictureBox(ControlCollection collectionParent, PictureBox pictureBox) {
   collectionParent.Add(pictureBox);
   pictureBox.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
}

// All your picture boxes that are important to you for whatever reason
// can now be worked with as a unit.
List<PictureBox> importantPictureBoxes = new list<PictureBox> { pb1, pb2, pb3, pb4 };
// Set up all the important PBs.
importantPictureBoxes.ForEach(pb => SetupPictureBox(pbBordermain.Controls, pb));
```

Even if this is just some prototype code, aren't going to be making changes to your prototype? Don't you want to start thinking like a professional programmer? It took me about 25 seconds to type up this code–don't fall into the land of spaghetti code. Think about what you're doing at all times and write *good* code.

Even the variable name `importantPictureBoxes` hints at *purpose*–what are these for? Why are you working with them? Characterize this purpose with a clear name that explains them. This means you don't have to write comments! The method names and variable names document your code for you. Awesome.

Answer (score 0):

First, short code is not always good code. While it's possible to express certain things in fewer lines, it's not always going to be clearer - and the whole point of using a linguistic coding language is clarity.

In this case, you could rearrange the code, but it'll be difficult to make it shorter while maintaining the functionality. Assuming order of the add/transparent functions don't matter, you could always arrange in columns, since C# ignores extra whitespace:

```
pbBordermain.Controls.Add(pb1); pb1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
pbBordermain.Controls.Add(pb2); pb2.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
pbBordermain.Controls.Add(pb3); pb3.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
pbBordermain.Controls.Add(pb4); pb4.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```